# C# plink ssh command to answer user input prompt

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ssh, plink

First of thanks for @MrPaulch for the below source code. I am new to C#-.NET world, need your help to get moving forward with my work. Below is the source code which I am working on currently. Code works fine but I wanted the below code to answer the user input prompt message.
For Ex: if I pass command like `sys rst` (stands for system restart), then there will be a prompt message saying `Are you sure [Y/N]?`. How to change below code in such that it should answer the prompt question. Most of the time i will execute same command only.

```
        public string RequestInfo(string remoteHost, string userName, string password, string[] lstCommands)
        {
            m_szFeedback = "Feedback from: " + remoteHost + "\r\n";
            string plink_path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "plink.exe");
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = plink_path, // A const or a readonly string that points to the plink executable
                Arguments = String.Format("-ssh {0}@{1} -pw {2}", userName, remoteHost, password),
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            Process p = Process.Start(psi);

            m_objLock = new Object();
            m_blnDoRead = true;

            AsyncReadFeedback(p.StandardOutput); // start the async read of stdout
            AsyncReadFeedback(p.StandardError); // start the async read of stderr            

            StreamWriter strw = p.StandardInput;
            foreach (string cmd in lstCommands)
            {
                //Eg: cmd = "sys rst";
                 strw.WriteLine(cmd); // send commands                 
            }
            strw.WriteLine("exit"); // send exit command at the end*/
            p.WaitForExit(); // block thread until remote operations are done
            return m_szFeedback;
        }
```

Thanks,
Shridhar

Comment: In foreach loop you need to read standard output.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardOutput

Comment: I tried it. but not sure how to do it. Do I need to do it asynchronously?

Comment: Does your cmd terminate with a "\n"?  You will not get a response without the proper return.  You using WriteLine which will add the return so maybe you are sending two returns.

Comment: Try adding a ConsoleReadLine() after the foreach loop to block.  It is possible you are getting the WaitForExit and terminating.

Comment: Is there any way I can discuss this with you offline? I am still not able to crack it.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to logon to a linux machine with ssh.  The return character is different on linux from windows.  See : https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows

Comment: No I am not trying to login to Linux box. In fact, login is successful but I just dont want command to execute and exit when it is expect Yes or No from user. I wanted issue Y/N before command returns. Whenever I write "y" writer, its showing as Invalid command.

Comment: It is still a linux machine and you need to correct return.  Instead of WriteLine use Write.   Then terminate the cmd with '\r'.

Comment: Use following : strw.Write(cmd + "\r");

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its worked now. :-)